# Get previous versions file in document Library

Tags: development, document-library, versioning, version-history

I'd like get the  previous versions of files in document Library,  passing as parameter the number of version.

```
else if(getFileObj.versionNumber!=0)
                                            {
                                                bool found = false;

                                                try
                                                {

                                                /


                                                    foreach(SPListItem items in allegatiCollegati)
                                                {
                                                    SPListItemVersionCollection collectionItemsVersions =items.Versions;

                                                    foreach(SPListItemVersion versions in collectionItemsVersions )
                                                    {
                                                        if(versions.VersionId == getFileObj.versionNumber)
                                                        {
                                                            SPListItem Item = items;
                                                            files.Add(new fileList() { file = Item.File.OpenBinary() });
                                                        }
                                                    }
                                                }
                                                found = true; if(fount== false) {throw new exception("II can't find any file with this version!");}
                                                }
                                                catch (Exception ex)
                                                {

                                                    throw new Exception(ex.Message);
                                                }
```

I tried with this code but it returns me always the last version of the file.

Answer (score 1):

look here, you must use SPFile not SPListItem:

```
foreach (SPFile file in folder.Files)..........


if (file.CheckOutType != SPFile.SPCheckOutType.None)
            {
                html.Append(" Estratto da<a href='" + mySiteHostUrl + file.CheckedOutByUser.LoginName + @"' class='author'>" + file.CheckedOutByUser.Name + @"</a>");
            }
            html.Append(@"</div>
        </div>");

            if (file.Versions.Count > 0)
            {
                html.Append("<div class='versions' style='display:none;' id='ver-id-" + file.Item.ID + "'><ul>");

                foreach (SPFileVersion version in file.Versions)
                {
                    html.Append("<li><div class='author'><a target='_blank' href='" + string.Format("{0}/{1}", file.Web.Url, version.Url) + "'>" + version.VersionLabel + "</a> " + version.Created.ToString() + " <a href='" + mySiteHostUrl + version.CreatedBy.LoginName + @"' class='author'>" + version.CreatedBy.Name + "</a></div></li>");
                }

                html.Append("</ul></div>");
            }
```